# FBPlacePickerViewController doesn't load any data

Tags: ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to use FBPlacePickerViewController and it doesn't seem to load any data.
Here is my code:

```
    FBPlacePickerViewController *picker = (FBPlacePickerViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    picker.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.radiusInMeters = 1000;
    picker.resultsLimit = 30;
    if([TonerAppDelegate instance].lastLocation != nil){
        picker.locationCoordinate = [TonerAppDelegate instance].lastLocation.coordinate;
        [picker loadData];
    }
    [TonerAppDelegate instance].lastLocationUpdateFunction = ^{
        picker.locationCoordinate = [TonerAppDelegate instance].lastLocation.coordinate;
        [picker loadData];
    };
```

It is an embed segue (iOS 6). I verify that the `picker` is a valid object. The `[picker loadData]` method does get called, and the coordinate data is perfectly valid. I am not getting any exceptions or warnings. I've allowed my app to access to my location in iOS and I double-verified that in Settings. My iPod is connected to the Internet and the connection works perfectly. All the other apps can use location services without any problem. So, there probably is a problem with my implementation of the place picker. I've also implemented the `-(void)placePickerViewControllerDataDidChange:(FBPlacePickerViewController *)placePicker` and `-(BOOL)placePickerViewController:(FBPlacePickerViewController *)placePicker shouldIncludePlace:(id<FBGraphPlace>)` methods of the delegate, and they aren't getting called either. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: I wasn't creating the Facebook session before displaying the place picker. I totally forgot about the session. It'd be nice to see Facebook add an assertion check in `loadData` method of the picker for an existing Facebook session. I've created the session, and THEN tried my code, and it works perfectly now.